# Laws Regarding content Hosted on your Website

Tags: forum, legal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Am I legally liable for user generated content and comments?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8001/am-i-legally-liable-for-user-generated-content-and-comments)

As a webmaster are you legally responsible for content posted on your website. For example a forum, would you be responsible for posts and threads made by other people if they were to break any laws?